# What's the most efficient way to write 1 MB from a compute shader and read it in a fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, buffer, fragment-shader, compute-shader

In OpenGL, there are so many different kinds of storage options: buffers, textures, framebuffers, etc. in OpenGL it seems very difficult to figure out which to use when.

I want to write a compute buffer that on each frame writes up to around 1 MB to some type of storage that is then read (read-only, random access) by a fragment shader. What is the most efficient mechanism to write that data from the compute shader so it's accessible in the fragment shader?

The data is made up of custom data structures: it is not a specific rendering type of data such as a texture.

Comment: There is only one kind of buffer. And there's only one kind of framebuffer. Textures are the only storage objects that have "kinds" to them. Also, *how* does the compute shader write this data? That's a big part of the efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there are multiple ways you could handle data transfer across pipeline.

**1. UBO**

Use when you have fixed amount of data large enough or you can group individual uniforms go with UBO. They are faster that SSBO but have size limitation and cant have variable size.
I see some vendors are even supporting UBO of size 2GB. But I am not sure if that still hold performance benefit of older UBOs. You can query though the limit on UBO size and decide for your self.

**2. SSBO**

When you have really large data then generally prefer SSBO. They are slower than UBO but can hold much larger data. Internally they are implemented using texture buffer memory.

Generally I prefer limit of 64 K data in UBO and anything larger than that in SSBO.

Another possible way to communicate is to use Transform Feedback. But I am not sure that will be efficient. But considering case when data computed by the compute shader will be processed by application before sending it to fragment shader. This case **Transform feedback** could be ideal.

Comment: In this case the data will go directly from compute shader to fragment shader without any processing in between.

Comment: I think try with UBO now cards have good size support for UBO blocks.

Comment: You mention UBO here but you can't write to a UBO from a compute shader, can you? So, that's not an option.